# What dialect is this man speaking?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

Ignoring the linguistically incorrect and wrong-headed things said in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLXIAYTIZVU), the more puzzling problem: I have no idea what dialect or type of English the man in the video is speaking. I have never heard English that sounds like this. I can't even tell whether or not he is a native speaker; [his website](http://englishpronunciation4all.com/AboutUs.html) implies that he is American, but doesn't say outright. Any ideas?

Comment: Wow. Yes, that accent is hard to place. It doesn't sound at all like any kind of American accent

Comment: Maybe his parents were immigrants, and he was born in the States, creating a sort of hybrid accent.

Comment: It sounds more like he's over-enunciating than speaking with an accent. Age may also play a role.

Comment: Yeah sounds like a combination of a foreign accent (Japanese?) and age.

Comment: Sounds to me like an american, with a slight Japanese accent who has physical difficulties pronouncing certain things, because of a stroke or other muscle-control issue, and is therefore over-enunciating slightly weirdly: basically what @Cerberus said.

Comment: @Mahnax: having foreign parents usually does not result in a 'mixed' or halfway accent, or any accent at all. You'll have the accent of the locality where you were raised (the kids in your neighborhood or school). In fact it's more likely ( but not very much) that they'll have a funny accent when speaking the parents' language.

Comment: @Mitch That is not always true; I work with a guy who was born and raised in Canada, but has a similar accent to that of his parents.

Comment: Maybe his over-enunciation is part of his teaching method?

Comment: @onomatomaniak: Either that, or he has a slight problem to pronounce certain sounds.

Comment: Sounds to me like an American trying to speak so clearly and slowly for the sake of Japanese English language students that it sounds a bit unnatural. Perhaps his use of Japanese symbols to translate the English terms shows that.

Comment: I lived in Japan for 10 years and I speak it with some fluency. To my ear, his English doesn't sound like it has a Japanese accent, and his Japanese has an English accent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first impression of Leonard Balazer was that he sounded like a elderly [Midwesterner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midwestern_United_States) who was over-enunciating. (The "boing-boing" audio compression artifacts don't help matters.)

His [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/people/Leonard-Balazer/100000709034175) confirms that Mr. Balazer grew up Saginaw, Michigan, and was educated in and spent his professional career in Michigan.

Comment: Yes, the vowels sound long, and heavy on the "Ohs" and "Ews", and the cadence is a bit sing-songy, as are common to the upper Midwest.

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to find any definite information on Professor Balazer other than the linked website, but my best guess is that either he is hyper-pronouncing because he is teaching/coaching pronunciation or else he is hyper-pronouncing due to injury/illness.

Comment: Or maybe it's because hyper-pronunciation is such a hit with the ladies.

Comment: @cheeken: the likeliest reason.

Comment: @cheeken - agreed <grin>